# Cannot use isset () on the result of a function call (you can use "null != Func ()" instead)

Tags: php, function, netbeans, detect

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\video-site\app\detect.php on line 45
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  234208  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
```

Previously my code was

```
if(!defined('WAP'))
    define('WAP', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || isset($_REQUEST['imode'])|| isset($_REQUEST['html'])|| isset($_REQUEST['Android'])|| isset($_REQUEST['iphone'])|| isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']));

    if (WAP)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) ? 'wap' : (isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) ? 'wap2' : (isset($_REQUEST['iphone']) ? 'iphone' : (isset($_REQUEST['imode']) ? 'imode' : (isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']) ? 'IEMobile' :(isset($_REQUEST['html']) ? 'html' : (isset($_REQUEST['Android']) ? 'Android' : '')))))));
```

And my IDE warned `Do Not Access SuperGlobal $_REQUEST Array Directly`
So I used this following code

```
if(!defined('WAP'))
{
    define('WAP', isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
}
    if (WAP)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'wap' : (isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'wap2' : (isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'iphone' : (isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'imode' : (isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'IEMobile' :(isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'html' : (isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'Android' : '')))))));
```

Here is `detect.php`

```
<?php
$userBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; 
if(stristr($userBrowser, 'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')) 
{
$_REQUEST['wap2'] = 1;
}

elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod"))
{
$_REQUEST['iphone'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone"))
{
$_REQUEST['iphone'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android"))
{
$_REQUEST['Android'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"IEMobile"))
{
$_REQUEST['IEMobile'] = 1;

}
elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'DoCoMo/' || 'portalmmm/'))
{
$_REQUEST['imode'] = 1;
}

elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'text/vnd.wap.wml')) 
{
$_REQUEST['wap'] = 1;
}
elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'text/html')) 
{
$_REQUEST['html'] = 1;
}


if(!defined('WAP'))
    define('WAP', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || isset($_REQUEST['imode'])|| isset($_REQUEST['html'])|| isset($_REQUEST['Android'])|| isset($_REQUEST['iphone'])|| isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']));

    if (WAP)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) ? 'wap' : (isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) ? 'wap2' : (isset($_REQUEST['iphone']) ? 'iphone' : (isset($_REQUEST['imode']) ? 'imode' : (isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']) ? 'IEMobile' :(isset($_REQUEST['html']) ? 'html' : (isset($_REQUEST['Android']) ? 'Android' : '')))))));  

if (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap')
      {
$browser_t = "mobile";
      }
elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap2')
      {


$browser_t = "mobile";


      }
elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'imode')
      {

$browser_t = "mobile";

      }
      elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'iphone')
      {


$browser_t = "smartphone";

      }
      elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'Android')
      {


$browser_t = "smartphone";

      }
       elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'IEMobile')
      {

$browser_t = "smartphone";

      }
      elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'html')
      {

     $mobile_browser = '0';

if(preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i',
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or 
    ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
        if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'iemobile')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
    $mobile_browser=0;
    }


if($mobile_browser>0){
   // do something wap

$browser_t = "mobile";

}
// non-mobile
else
{

$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";

}
   } else {
   // do something else html

$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
   }

      }


    else
    {
$mobile_browser = '0';

if(preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i',
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or 
    ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
$mobile_agents = array(
    'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
    'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
    'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
    'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
    'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
    'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
    'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
    'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
    'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)){
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'iemobile')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
    }
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
    $mobile_browser=0;
    }


if($mobile_browser>0){
   // do something wap

$browser_t = "mobile";

}
// non-mobile
else
{
$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
}

    }
     ?>
```

And `index.php`

```
<?php 
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";

if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='singlepage.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/singlepage.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='categories.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/categories.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
    }
else
    {
        include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }

?>
```

And `config.php`

```
<?php
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
$email_id = "s.hidayath@agileits.com";
?>
```

when index file is loaded it should detect device and redirect it to proper root but in my case it doesn't
I get following error

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: ALL_HTTP in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\video-site-2\app\detect.php on line 118
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0090  233992  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0230  295896  include( 'C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\video-site-2\app\detect.php' )  ..\index.php:11

( ! ) Warning: include(web/404.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\video-site-2\index.php on line 30
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0090  233992  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0

( ! ) Warning: include(): Failed opening 'web/404.html' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\video-site-2\index.php on line 30
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0090  233992  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
```

Comment: The error itself tells you what to use in place of `isset()`, *you can use "null !== func()" instead*

Comment: btw: with `isset` you can test multiple items at once ~ `isset( $var, $var2, $var3, $var4 )`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i tried it but doesn't work

Comment: Isset checks whether a variable "is set" and initialized. The result of a function - to my opinion - cannot be **not** set. To test if the variable "$_REQUEST['wap']" is set, your first construct is appropriate from the syntax point of view. I suggest you ignore the warning of your IDE in this case.

Comment: `stristr($userBrowser, 'DoCoMo/' || 'portalmmm/')` does **not** do what you probably thought it did. You need to use two distinct `stristr` checks, or a `preg_match`.

Comment: Also, you should probably check out browscap: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: the error says the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, **NetBeans IDE** shows you those warnings so that you don't trust the`$_REQUEST` values directly and validate it in some way. By checking `isset($_REQUEST['wap'])` you are already doing a part of checking which the IDE is suggesting. There can be other steps of this process, which you should do before you **use** it, like inserting to database. I ignore many of the NetBeans warnings, because, NetBeans doesn't know, what I am going to do with my inputs / variables. It just warns me about the best practices, which may or may not be the best for my case. And **warnings** should be taken as suggestions only, not something you **must** do.

Secondly, if you use [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), you don't need to use `isset()` additionally. Because, `filter_input()` is already doing it for you. As the documentation says,

> **Return Values** : Value of the requested variable on success, `FALSE` if the filter fails, or **`NULL` if the variable_name variable is not set**. If the flag `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE` is used, **it returns `FALSE` if the variable is not set** and `NULL` if the filter fails.

So you can just remove `isset()` and your code should work safely. But you may still want to check if the value was set to apply the alternative values. In that case just use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function, which will return `FALSE` when value returned from `filter_input()` is `NULL` / `FALSE`. So just negate the condition to match your case. Like this way -

```
if(!defined('WAP'))
{
    define('WAP', !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) || !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) || !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))|| !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
}

 if (WAP)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', !empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'wap' : (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'wap2' : (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'iphone' : (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'imode' : (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'IEMobile' :(!empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'html' : (!empty(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ? 'Android' : '')))))));
}
```

**Second Error**

> Notice: Undefined index: ALL_HTTP

I couldn't find any variable called `ALL_HTTP` in php documentation for [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/kr/reserved.variables.server.php). So check the link and find one which can serve your purpose. I'm not sure what you are actually trying to get with it, So I can't suggest any.

**Third Error**

> Warning: include(web/404.html): failed to open stream.

The error already says the file doesn't exist. So either the file isn't there or you have provided the path incorrectly. Pls check and fix that.

Comment: what about other thing is it right can you correct full file `detect.php`

Comment: @sanojlawrence I have added notes for your other issues above. Pls check the latest edit. Also if you have the same `isset()` issue in other files, I think you can fix it by the same way, if you understand my logic. Remember, we are not giving any code service here, we are just helping one another. :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `isset()` calls in your second example, and it should work.

```
if(!defined('WAP'))
{
    define('WAP', filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)|| filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)|| filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)|| filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)|| filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
if (WAP)
{
    define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'wap' : (filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'wap2' : (filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'iphone' : (filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'imode' : (filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'IEMobile' :(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'html' : (filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) ? 'Android' : '')))))));
}
```

This is because the `filter_input()` function will return a value that evaluates to true/false already, so you do not need the `isset()` as well. Check out the return values in the [PHP Manual for filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) for more info.

You may also want to check out `empty()` and `is_null()` and see how they compare with `isset()` in their usage. The function `empty()` would make more sense in this situation.

For the issue with undefined `%_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']`, you should use `isset()` there to first check if the variable exists. Example:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']) && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']), 'OperaMini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}
```

The error with the missing 404 file is something I cannot resolve without knowing where the file is placed. However, the include you are using is looking for:

`C:\Users\sanoj\Documents\NetBeansProjects\video-site-2\web\404.html`

You either need to create/move the file in that location, or change the include path to point to the right file location. You may give me the file location and I will give you the correct include path.

Comment: what about other thing is it right can you correct full file `detect.php`

Comment: Please see the second half of my answer for the additional info on the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a more lisible code:

Step 1: you get the variables matching your needs in one array

```
$tab=array_filter(filter_input_array(INPUT_SERVER,Array(
    'wap'     =>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'wap2'    =>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'imode'   =>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'html'    =>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'Android' =>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'iphone'  =>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
    'IEMobile'=>FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
```

Step 2: Use the first variable detected

```
if(!defined('WAP'))&&(count($tab)) {
   define('WAP', $tab[0]);
}
```

Also, as already said in other answers, you have to use `filter_input()` functions in order to satisfy your IDE warning `Do Not Access SuperGlobal $_REQUEST Array Directly`

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()` as :

```
    if(!defined('WAP')){
      if(isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || ..){
      $wap = $_REQUEST['wap']);
      $wap2 = $_REQUEST['wap2']);
      //other variables
      define('WAP', $wap || $wap2 || ..);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the first part does not directly answer your question, it is an important note and will probably save you a lot of grief in your application. You are using constants incorrectly, which can come back to bite you.

Consider the following code:

```
if(!defined('WAP'))
    define('WAP', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) 
    || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) || isset($_REQUEST['imode'])
    || isset($_REQUEST['html'])|| isset($_REQUEST['Android'])
    || isset($_REQUEST['iphone'])|| isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']));
```

These lines say "if WAP is not defined, then assign WAP a value of true if any of the following are in the `REQUEST` scope: wap, wap2, imode, html, Android, iphone, or IEMobile. If they are NOT in the request scope, assign `WAP` constant the value false.

I know this may feel trivial, but constants should have the same value regardless of any other system reality. Constants should be very easy to discover values for. Look at how PHP uses constants to give an idea. `E_NOTICE` is always the same value. Thus, you can use the integer (8) that represents `E_NOTICE` or you can use `E_NOTICE` constant to get the same exact result.

If, on the other hand, `E_NOTICE` was equal to 8, unless you specified that notices should trigger a fatal error, in which case `E_NOTICE` was equal to 16 (aka `E_CORE_ERROR`), then you'd have a bit of a confusing mess on your hands.

## Why does this matter in this instance?

Consider your code:

```
if(!defined('WAP'))
{
    define('WAP', isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) 
    || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) 
    || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
    || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
    || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
    || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
    || isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
}
```

You are doing a lot of mental gymnastics to ensure that a constant is set to a specific session. While there are ways to clean up this code so as not to trigger an error, *it will still contain an issue which may come back to bite you*, i.e. you are using constants where you should be using a variable, or, better yet, a function.

Like, the following:

```
function is_wap()
{
    return (filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    || filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
}
```

Now, replace `WAP` with `is_wap()`.

More in line with your question, you ***cannot*** use `isset()` against a direct function call. You can do one of three things to circumvent this:

1. As PHP suggests, instead use `null !==`. This is probably the easiest shorthand solution.

Example:

```
if (isset(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)))
    ...
```

Can just as easily be written as

```
if (null !== ($imode = filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)))
    ...
```

Getting you your variable assignment as well.

2. If you insist on using `isset()` then you can assign the variable beforehand.

   $imode = filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   if (isset($imode))
       ...
3. You can use `function` return values to determine the result. You can even create a custom function to handle your logic for you if a third-party or built-in function doesn't have the right return value.

For example, if you just want to ensure that a value is not equal to null (and you're OK with it being false), you can use this:

```
function isNotNull($val)
{
    return ($val !== null);
    // note that, because you've essentially passed the function result,
    // you could use this line instead:
    // return isset($val);
}
```

Then, in your code, you can use the custom function:

```
isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) 
|| isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'wap2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) 
|| isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'imode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
|| isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'html', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
|| isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'Android', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
|| isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'iphone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
|| isNotNull(filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST, 'IEMobile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
```

Note that because `filter_input` does return false if the filter fails and null if the variable doesn't exist. So, it may be more advantageous to omit `isset` entirely which will cause your logical check to determine if a variable exists without the possibility that the filter might fail.

I should note that the probability of a filter failing in production is low. Going full circle to my original point, one of the reasons it is so low is because the filters are constants, and **ALWAYS** represent the same thing.